# Exclude one row of duplicate rows in Django

Tags: django

I have a model like this (simplified):

```
class TrainingMoment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    # Moment of the day, 2 is afternoon for example
    moment_nr = models.IntegerField()
    is_group_moment = models.BooleanField()
```

On a given date and moment_nr, 2 rows can exist. One with `is_group_moment=False` and one with `is_group_moment=True`.
For every one of the duplicates in `TrainingMoment.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date,end_date))` i want to exclude the row with `is_group_moment = True`.

Note that I only want to exclude the rows with `is_group_moment=True` if there is a row with the same date and moment_nr with `is_group_moment=False`.

I have tried using annotate() together with group_by() to get the duplicate rows to begin with, but that gives med only one of each duplicate row set, instead of both as I want.

For example:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ date       moment_nr is_group_moment   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-10-01 1         True              ║
║ 2013-10-02 1         True              ║
║ 2013-10-02 1         False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 1         False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 2         False             ║
║ 2013-10-04 2         True              ║
║ 2013-10-04 2         False             ║
║ 2013-10-01 1         True              ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Should be:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ date       moment_nr is_group_moment    ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-10-01 1          True              ║
║ 2013-10-02 1          False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 1          False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 2          False             ║
║ 2013-10-04 2          False             ║
║ 2013-10-01 1          True              ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have another model, Activity, which stores training time where I want to use the queryset from above to get correct summing of the week:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activitytype = models.ForeignKey(ActivityType)
    trainingmoment = models.ForeignKey(TrainingMoment)
    # Time in minutes
    time = models.IntegerField()
```

Summary of what i want to accomplish:

```
# 1. Get training moments for a given period, for example a week (no problem here)
tms_for_summing = TrainingMoment.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date,end_date))

# 2. Filter out duplicates in the way described above

# 3. Use the resulting queryset (tms_for_summing) to sum activity
summed_activity = Activity.objects.filter(trainingmoment__in = tms_for_summing)
```

**Edit**
Here follows some additional explanation for those who wonder about my db design:

This is as you have probably figured out, a training logging app. In the case in my question, the page I want to achieve is a planning page. All the training moments are planned training moments. An individual athlete can plan his own training. Also, a trainer can plan training for a group of athletes at the same time. This becomes a group moment (a training moment with is_groupmoment = True and also a many to many field linking to the specific group). If the athlete plans a group moment on a moment nr and date where he also has a group moment, his own moment should override this moment.

**A practical, very simplified example**

I have the following individual moments:
Day, Momentnr
Monday 1
Tuesday 1

And the following group moment:
Day, Momentnr
Tuesday 1
Wednesday 1

In the table where I show the moments and sum activity connected to these moments, I want to show the individual moments from monday and tuesday, but also the group moment from wednesday since there is no individual moment overriding the group moment there.
I could do the summing in the view using pure python code by summing the moments one by one, while checking if there are both group moments and individual moment at the same date an momentnr, but this would be a really ugly and slow way to do it, specially when summing a whole year.

**What I have tried**

I have tried this:

```
training_moments = TrainingMoment.objects.filter(date__range=('2013-08-19','2013-10-28'))
moments_to_exclude = training_moments.annotate(num_dates=Count('date'), num_momentnrs=Count('momentnr')).filter(num_dates__gt= 1, num_momentnrs__gt=1)
```

This is close. With this I get one moment for every "time slot" (where moment nr and date is the same for group moment and individual moment). The problem is that I need to get both the "colliding" moments. Then I can exclude the group moments from the resulting query set and finally have the moments to exclude when summing training moments in my app.

```
moments_to_exclude = moments_to_exclude.exclude(is_group_moment=True)
desired_result = training_moments.exclude(pk__in=moments_to_exclude)
```

Comment: Please look at my extended answer and see if it isn't helpful

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: [I used this](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Comment: I think you dont need to use two models - `Moment` and `Activity` - because both of them contains time, and this time data may conflict with such schema, and so your data will be inconsistent. You can store just one model - `Activity` which contains `start_datetime`, and `end_datetime`. It will be more intuitive, it will exclude data inconsistency, and you will be able to easily sum them, and perform other operations.

Comment: You could you this solution for managing model with `start` and `end` datetime fields: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#timeframedmodel

Comment: @GillBates start_date, and end_date is just what I use to get all training moments during a time period. Each training moment has a given date and moment number (moment nr 1 is naturally morning, moment  nr 2 is after lunch and so on). The model activity represents all training during one training moment, like 60 minutes biking and 45 minutes running.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
TrainingMoment.objects.filter(date=… , moment_nr=…).exclude(is_group_moment=True)
```

I suggest you read a little about the models API in the django docs and play around with the `manage.py shell`

**edit**

So this might not be the perfect solution but it is certainly the direction you want. What you need is to break it down to two classes: Moment and Trainee. Trainee will have one boolean field and one foreign key for moment.

```
class Moment(models.Model):
    date = …
    number = …

class Trainee(models.Model):
    is_group = models.BooleanField()
    moment = models.ForeignKey(Moment)
```

What you earn here is that there are no duplicate Moment objects with same date + number fields, so it's easier to filter on the range without too much headache. At the same time, filtering on the True values is easier (do it with a method) and you can do it client size (even by just checking the amount of related trainees).

You'll have to add custom constraints to prevent adding objects with the same information but that's not very complicated to do

**Edit 2**

To answer you on your comments, let's take your example table. Say your current layout looks like this:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ date       moment_nr is_group_moment   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-10-01 1         True              ║
║ 2013-10-02 1         True              ║
║ 2013-10-02 1         False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 1         False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 2         False             ║
║ 2013-10-04 2         True              ║
║ 2013-10-04 2         False             ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Then with my design suggestion it would look like this:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ date       moment_nr related trainees  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-10-01 1         True              ║
║ 2013-10-02 1         True, False       ║
║ 2013-10-03 1         False             ║
║ 2013-10-03 2         False             ║
║ 2013-10-04 2         True, False       ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Because now *you don't have duplicate rows*, i.e. it will actually merge the two Moment objects from the earlier design to one object with two related Trainee objects.

In other words, your final code from the end of the question will simply look like this:

```
# 1. Get training moments for a given period, for example a week (no problem here)
tms_for_summing = TrainingMoment.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date,end_date))    

# 3. Use the resulting queryset (tms_for_summing) to sum activity
summed_activity = Activity.objects.filter(trainingmoment__in = tms_for_summing)
```

Which, frankly, can be also cut down to one line:

```
summed = Activity.objects.filter(trainingmoment__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is a bit harder than that. I forgot to write that I want the all objects in a date range like: TrainingMoment.objects.filter(date__range=('2013-01-01, '2013-12-31')). Also, I only want to exclude the rows with is_group_moment = True if there is also a row with is_group_moment=False on the same date and moment_nr. I will update my question.

Comment: So what? You can just add the exclude at the end of range and add a condition to check if there's a similar row before you filter

Comment: Looking at the edit, just use aggregation or what have you to check if there are duplicates and then filter using my simple example

Comment: If I do as you say, wouldn´t the rows with `is_group_moment=True` that doesn´t have a duplicate one with `is_group_moment=False` get excluded to?

Comment: They would. I think I understand the problem better now. I'll have to think about it but to be frank I think the solution would eventually be through a different db design

Comment: There. Hope this helps

Comment: I am very grateful for all your efforts, but I cannot see how to do to with your suggestion to present similar results as in the table I added in my question (this doesn´t mean it´s not possible, of course). The tricky part for me is to find out how to give priority to the non-group moments over the group moments without using foor loop and breaking the queryset, which I need for my summing. The reason for this tricky question is because I want to give the user the possibility to view his own training moments, and the group training moments in the same table.

Comment: The idea is that my suggestion obliterates the need to find duplicates. You just add a display method for the Moment object that displays the related objects according to your condition. Then you filter on the range and use the method **on the client side** to show it the proper way. You don't need to filter those out so it's easier

Comment: With client side, do you mean javascript?

Comment: No, I mean do `{% for moment in moments %}` then do `{{ moment.my_group_display_method }}` wherever needed. I would've shown in the answer but I don't know how the end result should look like. The point being you don't need to look for duplicate Moment rows instead you will have one Moment with two related Group objects

Comment: Ok! I have already solved displaying the moment one by one as you described. Maybe not as nice as in your suggestion. My problem is that I have another model, Activity, which stores training time for each moment. I need to use a queryset with the moments sorted as earlier described, to do get correct summing of the activity. For example, I want to sum all training time for a week. I will update my question again to make this more clear.

Comment: See edit. Looking at your updated question I think my solution is exactly what you're looking for. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help! I like your last edit a lot, but I realised this: In your last suggestion it seems to me that the same training moment can be both a group moment and not at the same time. That is not how it should be. There can be 2 different training moments with different activities connected to them at the same date and momentnr. One of the moments is then group moment and one of them is not group moment. But you are closing in on the reward :)

Comment: I changed the name from Group to Trainee. What I'm getting at here is that TrainingMoment will now represent a moment in time which can be linked to different Trainees, some would be group and some not. The design needs to fit your application, and in this case, avoiding duplication makes sense. In general really, when working on an app that has a time-span of events, you usually want the object representing the time or date to be a model of its own because it can usually relate to all sorts of different events happening at the same time

Comment: In other words, a moment can not be group and not group at the same time, because it isn't a group at all. It represents something different now, while Trainee (or Group or what have you) represents the trainees themselves, which can be a group or (I'm guessing) singular, and can share the same moment

Comment: @LordNelson see changes (and comments)

Comment: I am not sure if your solution solved my problem. Please have a look at my last edit.

Comment: would you like to talk about this in a chat as I don't entirely understand what's missing in my solution that you're still troubled about. I opened one here's the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40134/exclude-one-row-of-duplicate-rows-in-django